# How to share a background job queue between Ruby and Python apps

Tags: python, ruby, queue

I have a Rails app which will schedule jobs. I would like to write my worker program in Python. What is a good mechanism to share a job queue between two different languages? All the queues I looked at (Sidekiq, Resque, Celery) seem to be language-specific.

Is it a good idea to write a worker in Ruby which just forks another process that's written in python (using something like [Kernel#exec or Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#M005971))?

Comment: Try rabbitmq, It has a client for both

Answer (score 1):

Resque is a ruby client library for Redis.  Redis is a stand-alone queue, it runs as a separate process. It is not language-specific.

You can use Resque (or any other ruby Redis library) to add jobs to the queue, and a Python redis library to provide the workers that work off the queue.

Or you can use some other queue software -- at a simple not very high performing solution, you could even leave your jobs in a postgres table.

The key is that one side is going to put a description of a job onto an external queue of some kind (Redis, postgres table, rabbitmq, something else).  And the other side is going to take job descriptions off the external queue and actually execute them. The 'job descriptions' are just key/values, where the values are strings or arrays of strings or whatever. This is what happens anyway with Resque, although it may make it look like something more magical is working.

You will probably want to work with Redis (or your queue store of choice) a bit to understand how it actually works and what's going on, and understand what the libraries you are using to interact with the queue store (eg Resque) are actually doing (or even write a bit of code directly against the queue store without a client library) to make sure you understand what's going on and can set it up appropriately and debug it when needed

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, a Resque queue is just a Redis key-value map that receives JSON in a specific format (a hash of “class” and “args”). That means you can push stuff on the Resque queue from your Python Redis client or directly from the command line:

```
redis-cli rpush "resque:queue:myqueue" '{"class":"MyClass","args":["arg1"]}'
```